# Highchart, How to resize auto if there is a lot of data, then scale accordingly to make all the data visible

Tags: highcharts

Highchart, How to resize auto if there is a lot of data, then scale accordingly to make all the data visible.

[`Link demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/teeraphongsing/5940ku6r/3/)

The problem is that Football-Player there is so much information that the charts can't show them all. I want to show all data no size and height restrictions. just show all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt your chart's height to the number of points. Below you can find a simple implementation of such feature:

```
 let spacePerPoint;
 let allowChartRedraw = true;

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
     type: 'bar',
     width: 600,
     height: 600,
     events: {
       load() {
         spacePerPoint = this.plotSizeX / this.series[0].points.length;

         if (this.renderer.forExport) {
           Highcharts.drawTable(this);
         }
       },
       redraw() {
         if (allowChartRedraw) {
           allowChartRedraw = false;

           this.setSize(
             null,
             this.chartHeight - this.plotSizeX + this.series[0].points.length * spacePerPoint
           );


           allowChartRedraw = true;
         }
       }
     }
   },
   ...
 });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cy7gd0ab/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize